# If condition doesn't trigger in the Express route

Tags: javascript, express

This is really weird, and I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. I have a checkbox that, when checked, sets `searchByName` parameter to `true`in some React component. Then, I'm using `axios` to `.get` a route that needs to search and return the list of users. If `searchByName` is `true`, then MongoDB is queried by name, and when it's `false`, it queries by using some other parameters.

The problem is, that when I console `searchByName` in the route, I see it's value properly (either true or false), however, my condition that checks if it's true or false doesn't trigger, and I'm always getting the results for the `true` case. I added `console.log("Im name")` and `console.log("Im city")` to see whether or not the code triggers, but it's always the `name` case, even if `searchByName` is false.

Could you help to figure this out?

```
// @route   GET api/report/:search/:searchByName
// @desc    Get users
// @access  Private
router.get("/:search/:searchByName", auth, async (req, res) => {
  if (req.params.searchByName) {
    console.log("im name");
    try {
      const query = req.params.search;
      const reports = await Report.find({
        name: { $regex: query },
        isPublic: true
      })
        .select([
          "name",
          "status",
          "startDate",
          "country",
          "zipcode",
          "city",
          "address"
        ])
        .populate("users", [
          "name",
          "status",
          "startDate",
          "country",
          "zipcode",
          "city",
          "address"
        ]);

      res.json(reports);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.json(err);
      res.status(500).send("Server Error");
    }
  } else if (!req.params.searchByName) {
    console.log("im city");
    try {
      const query = req.params.search;
      const reports = await Report.find({
        $or: [{ city: { $regex: query } }, { zipcode: { $regex: query } }]
      })
        .select([
          "status",
          "startDate",
          "country",
          "zipcode",
          "city",
          "address"
        ])
        .populate("users", [
          "status",
          "startDate",
          "country",
          "zipcode",
          "city",
          "address"
        ]);

      res.json(reports);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.json(err);
      res.status(500).send("Server Error");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Is it really `true` or `false`, or is it actually `"true"` or `"false"` (I mean, strings?)

Comment: Yes! That was the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `searchByName` param is a string. Use `req.params.searchByName === 'true|false'` to check if it is `true` or `false`.